# Loading data from several files into a single variable using python

Tags: python, performance, file-io, io

I have a bunch of files (`bar0,bar1,bar2...,bar20`) in a folder (`foo`). Each file have 6000 lines of the format

```
1   v1
2   v2
3   v3
```

etc. `vi` are all integers

I want to go over all the files in the folder and load the data into a single list adding the values of the appropriate position. Currently, I'm doing this

```
for i in range (20):
   fin = open('{dir}/ions{i}'.format(dir=self.locDir,i=i)).readlines()[:]
   for j in range (len(fin)):
       line = fin[j]
       words = line.split()
       x = int(words[0])
       y = int(words[0])
       if not x in self.ionDist.X:
          self.ionDist.X.append(x)
       if len(self.ionDist.Y) == j:
          self.ionDist.Y.append(0)
       self.ionDist.Y[j] += y
```

`ionDist` is a simple class

```
class dist:
    def __init__(self):
        self.X = []
        self.Y = []
```

This is very slow however (I have 80 such folders and it take several minutes each time). What is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want self.X at all? Isn't self.X the index of self.Y?

Comment: @JohnDoe There is no real use for it. I kept it mainly to be sure I think about things correctly. The run time has improved dramatically, thank you.

Comment: Okay, if you get rid of self.X, and optimize the summations, you can significantly optimize this code. I will post a code snippet later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you don't need self.X, here's my solution:

```
for i in range(20):
 fin = open('{dir}/ions{i}'.format(dir=self.locDir,i=i)).readlines()
 y = lambda(x:eval(x.strip().split()[1]),fin) 
 if len(y) > len(self.Y): self.Y = self.Y + [0]* (len(y) - len(self.Y))
 elif len(y) < len(self.Y): y = y + [0]*(len(self.Y) - len(y))
 self.Y = [ a+b for (a,b) in zip(self.Y,y)]
```

In case all your files have the same number of rows, you can remove the if, elif statements too.

Comment: Thanks. I've had to change the third line (the one with the ``lambda``) to another one ``vv = [int(float(line.split()[1])) for line in fin]`` since the original one did work as expected.

Comment: I hadn't tested the code. Your edit is better: using list comprehension is preferred over using lambda.